# How can I reformat a string of C# code to get it properly indented?

Tags: notepad++, string-formatting

I've found that if I copy C# code from off of a website, and paste it into Notepad++, it can look ugly.  Basically it's all on 1 line.  Is there a way to format code, e.g. a way to take something like 1 long line of C# code, and then properly indent the code?

Comment: You can paste it into Visual Studio (Express).

Comment: (VS Express is free by the way)

Comment: Visual studio has code autoformating with Ctrl-K-D. MonoDevelop and SharpDevelop probably have a similar feature.

Comment: Rather sounds like Rod would like to use Notepad++

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, once copied and reformatted in Visual Studio, the OP cound copy it out again into Notepad++  - the only good use for Visual Studio?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, if you're interested, you can in fact use Notepad++; please see my answer.

Comment: @MartinJames, if you're interested, you can actually format C-style languages with Notepad++; have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're trying to format a C-style language you can in fact use Notepad++ - but you'll need to install TextFX. You can do that via the Plugin Manager (`Plugins` -> `Plugin Manager`) or by downloading the ZIP [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/). Once you've downloaded the ZIP just drop that DLL into the Plugins folder for Notepad++ (which is going to be under the install directory) and (re)start Notepad++.

Then when you want to use it use the `TextFX` -> `TextFX Edit` -> `Reindent C++ Code` option from the menu. It will make something like this:

```cs
namespace Hello
{
public class MyClass
  {
 }
}
```

look like this:

```cs
namespace Hello
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, when you paste the code, you can go to Edit --> Advanced --> Format Document

In Notepad++ you may be out of luck on the single line thing, but you can go to Language --> C --> C# (or language of code)

Comment: Setting thr Language in npp controls the syntax highlighting. I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: It also sets regions / collapsible areas, but you're right, the main formatting would be done in VS using the Format Document (not in Npp)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, npp does in fact do formatting of C type languages. Download TextFX [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/) and you can just drop the DLL in that ZIP into the Plugins folder.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yep, TextFX -> Edit -> Reindent C++ Code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, hey thanks! I did that in fact. I really appreciate that and I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 2):

To add format and other C# specific benefits to notepad++ install a CS-Script Plugin via the Plugin Manager (Plugins -> Plugin Manager)

Answer (score 1):

notepad++ won't format the code.

Follow this steps to do:-

1. Open visual studio
2. drag n drop the file on VS
3. Click on Edit menu
4. Click on Advanced
5. Click on Format Document.

Comment: Actually, npp does format C style languages. Download TextFX [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/) and drop the DLL into the Plugins folder.